# adb shell input variable right format

Tags: python, input, environment-variables, format, adb

In my VTS host-side Python test script I can't seem to find the right format to input a touchscreen tap at a variable. For input text it worked with .format but that didn't really work well this time too

```
x = 528
y = 1270
coord = 528 1270

device.shell('input touchscreen tap x y')
device.shell('input touchscreen tap coord')
```

I tried by using a single variable, or defining each x and y, but that doesn't get me anywhere if the formatting is wrong.

Comment: If you have a single variable coord that contains both x and y as a string, you can directly include that: device.shell('input touchscreen tap ' + coord)

Comment: You forgot to mention to tell us the context of your script. Based on your code it seems like you are talking about an VTS host-side Python test script, I have added this information to your question. Next time please don't forget such important details, otherwise you may not get any answer or response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right format is an f string:

```
adb.shell(f'input touchscreen tap {Center_x} {Center_y}')
```